# Is there anything missing in my first part of the pygame Alien Invasion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

update:
Based on the answers, I tried some changes.
I change the part of ship.py

```
def update(self):

   if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
       self.rect.centery += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_fator
   if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > 0:
       self.rect.centery -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

   # update the rect based on the self.center
   self.rect.centery = self.center
```

into the next:

```
    def update(self):
        """based on the moving signal to change the ship's position"""
        #update the ship's center value, not the rect
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
            self.rect.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_fator
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > 0:
            self.rect.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # update the rect based on the self.center
        self.rect.centery = self.center
```

BUT STILL NOT WORKING.
Feels bad.

---

I tried to used the same way of the textbook taught me to make a similar pygame, but now get stacked. The game named Alien Invasion, well-known as a python newbie's first try and the textbook Python Crash Course's project.

I have learned the Python Crash Course Chapter 12 and typed every line of the textbook codes my self. I thought I understand them. 
So I transfer the game into a horizon version. But I failed. I cannot use the key up and down to control my ship, is there anyone can help me? I put it on my github with the link https://github.com/Ruwzy/Python-Crash-Course-Practises/tree/master/PCC_12/Practice_12_5, and also the codes below.

settings.py

```
class Settings():
"""Store all the classes of the Alien_Invasion's settings"""

  def __init__(self):
      """ initialize the game's setting"""
      # Screen Settings
      self.screen_width = 1600
      self.screen_height = 800
      self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

      # ship settings
      self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys

import pygame


def check_keydown_events(event, ship):
    """response to the keydown"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = True

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """response to the keyup"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = False

def check_events(ship):
    """response to the keyboard and the mouse"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ship)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """update the screen's image, and change to the new screen"""
    # Redraw the screen each time starts the loop
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    # show the lastest drawing screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """ initialize the ship and set its original position"""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # load the ship's image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # set every new ship to the center of left
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.midleft
        self.rect.left = self.screen_rect.left

        #store float type value in setting center
        self.center = float(self.rect.centery)

        # moving signal
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        """based on the moving signal to change the ship's position"""
        #update the ship's center value, not the rect
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
            self.rect.centery += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_fator
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > 0:
            self.rect.centery -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # update the rect based on the self.center
        self.rect.centery = self.center 

    def blitme(self):
        """ draw the ship at a certain position"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

import game_functions as gf 


def run_game():
    """ initialize the game and creat a screen"""
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien_Invasion")

    # built a ship
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)

 # Start the game's main loop
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)

run_game()
```

I cannot move the ship to go up and down, wish someone could help me. I really spent a lot of time on debugging it.

Comment: I *think* it's because `ship.update()` is setting `self.rect.centery = self.center`, yet `self.center` is never changed after `ship.__init__()`.

Comment: I think it probably is the question! I'll check it and fix it later, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the method `update`:

> ```py
> def update(self):
>
>    if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
>        self.rect.centery += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_fator
>    if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > 0:
>        self.rect.centery -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
>
>    # update the rect based on the self.center
>    self.rect.centery = self.center
> ```

In this method `self.rect.centery` is changed, but at the end it is overwritten by `elf.rect.centery = self.center`.
Change it to:

```py
def update(self):

    if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_fator
    if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

    # update the rect based on the self.center
    self.rect.centery = round(self.center)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this problem. But I change the code and run it, I still cannot move the ship with button up and down. Your way of solving it gave me some idea, I'll check it later.